# unicode-math, Fira Math: Fira Math font lacks scalable slash delimiters; how to pull from a different math font?

Tags: unicode-math

I'm making slides using `beamer` with Fira as the main font, and I want to use Fira Math to match it. However, I've found that Fira Math does not seem to have scalable forward slash delimiters, which I would like to use. Here's a MWE; it doesn't use `beamer` because the problem can be illustrated just by using Fira Math.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}

\begin{document}
    $\left/\begin{tabular}{l}a\\b\end{tabular}\right/$
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image]

If I comment out the `\setmathfont{Fira Math}` line, I get what I want for the slashes, but of course it doesn't use the Fira Math font otherwise (not shown here):

[image]

Is there a way I can tell `unicode-math` to "borrow" these forward slash delimiters from another font that includes them, while using Fira Math for everything else? I know it's possible to do something like `\setmathfont{...}[range={...}]`, where `range=` specifies which characters to pull from a particular font, but I'm not sure what to put for the scalable forward slash delimiters. I tried `\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range={\left/,\right/}]`, but that gives me a `Missing number` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with a different font than Latin Modern Math and use a “simpler” syntax that doesn't require guessing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setmathfont{Fira Math}

\newfontface{\bigslashes}{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[NFSSFamily=bigslashes]
\DeclareSymbolFont{bigslashes}{TU}{bigslashes}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{/}{\mathord}{operators}{`/}{bigslashes}{`/}

\begin{document}

$/a/ + \left/\begin{matrix} a\\b\\c\\d \end{matrix}\right/$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The big slashes aren't cut in the same way as in Fira Math, but…

Comment: yes we really ought to add latex/nfss wrappers around `\U...` declarations so you can do a combination of the two

Answer (score 4):

`range` needs a bit of help for delimiters

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}

\setmathfont[range={`/}]{Latin Modern Math}
\let\lmfam\allocationnumber % fam allocated above for latin modern

\begin{document}
\Udelcode `/= \lmfam `/
   $/a/  + \left/\begin{tabular}{l}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}\right/$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm running into trouble figuring out how to check the math fam for a different font though (I want to try out some other possibilities for the replacement font). When I run your example with `\showlists` uncommented, I get a weird error message and no PDF output: `C:\Users\[snip]\test.tex:11: OK. [\showlists]`. Any idea on what to do with this error message? It's unfortunately not very informative as to what's going wrong.

Comment: no that is not an error, the showlists interaction looks like an error as tex stops and shows the current state, but there should be a better way, I did ping Will in chat last night to see if he had an idea, I'll probably add something later. but look in the log and  you will see the 4 shown

Comment: @Jigsaw try now, I updated so 4 is found automatically